# Visual Studio 2008: Need help finding the custom build step batch file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build

While building a Visual Studio 2008 project some it says "Performing Custom Build Step" and fails in that step due to some error.                                                       I can't find what batch script has been configured as a custom build step. As explained in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293663.aspx I searched for  in the .vcproj xml file but can't find any.
    Neither can I find any value specified in Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Build Events->Pre-Build Event->Command Line. Please assist how to find where is that batch script specified.

Comment: Is it a custom build event for any project on which your project depends on?

Comment: I really don't know. Are you saying I already have looked in the right places?